# how to loop through selected list of forms in Ms Access

Tags: vba, forms, loops, ms-access

I am trying to loop through a selected list of forms in Ms Access.
Like we can do it with sheets in Excel in this way

```
For Each shtSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet1"))
```

Is there a way to do some similar thing in Access for forms?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
Dim f As Form
Dim arr
arr = Array("Form1", "Form2")
Dim element

For Each element In arr
    Set f = Forms(element)
Next
```

But `set f= Forms(element)` will fail if the form is not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can list them as objects:

```vb
Public Function ListSomeForms()

    Dim Form        As Object
    Dim FormNames   As Variant
    Dim Item        As Variant
    
    FormNames = Array("FormName1", "FormName2")
    
    For Each Item In FormNames    
        Set Form = CurrentProject.AllForms(Item)
        Debug.Print Form.Name, Form.IsLoaded

        ' Loop controls.
        DoCmd.OpenForm Form.Name, acDesign
        ' For Each Control In Forms(Form.Name) 
        '     Do stuff ...
        ' Next
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Form.Name

    Next

    Set Form = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Gustav 
can you tell me how can I loop through my selected control names with the above code in the same way, like I put control names in the table and then from the active form I loop through the controls?

Comment: You must open the form, perhaps in designmode, to be able to loop the controls. See expanded answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

@storax @gustav
Both of you guys gave just the perfect solution I asked for.

As for me, I ended up putting form names in a table and then calling those through recordsets.

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tsubforms")

Do Until rs.EOF
Set frm = rs!SubForm

With frm
    DoCmd.OpenForm frm, acViewDesign, , , , acHidden
    For Each ctrl In Forms(frm).Controls
            Debug.Print ctrl.Name
End With
rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

just putting my solution so if it could help out anyone else.

I would appreciate if somebody finds any of my mistakes in my code or can let me know of something better than this.